# Unable to use the result of a ParseQuery

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I'm doing a query to fetch a table .
As you can see in the code below, the list LOCALparseQuestionList is populated correctly during the for loop inside the findInBackground. Once it's done, the LOCALparseQuestionList is empty (the log prints 0 size and I see the same when using the debugger).
How should I fetch correctly the data and populate my LOCALparseQuestionList?

```
 public List<QuestionStruct> getParseAllQuestions() {
    final List<QuestionStruct> LOCALparseQuestionList = new ArrayList<QuestionStruct>();
    // Select All Query
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> questionQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("triviaQuestions");
    questionQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> allQuestions, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                parseQuestionList = allQuestions;
                Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved " + allQuestions.size() + " All questions");
                for (ParseObject qu : allQuestions) {
                    QuestionStruct currentQuestion = new QuestionStruct();
                    currentQuestion.setID(qu.getInt("id"));
                    currentQuestion.setQuestion(qu.getString("question"));
                    currentQuestion.setCorrectAnswer(qu.getString("correct"));
                    currentQuestion.setPossibleAnswer(qu.getString("wrong_1"));
                    currentQuestion.setPossibleAnswer(qu.getString("wrong_2"));
                    currentQuestion.setPossibleAnswer(qu.getString("wrong_3"));
                    currentQuestion.setPossibleAnswer(qu.getString("correct"));
                    LOCALparseQuestionList.add(currentQuestion);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved  " + LOCALparseQuestionList.size() + " LOCALparseQuestionList ");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "questionList size: " + LOCALparseQuestionList.size());

    return LOCALparseQuestionList;
}
```

Comment: look at your parse data console for the class=triviaQuestions. check the ACL property value to determine whether or not your currentUser has READ privs on the rows of  that class??

Comment: :( Learn C#. Or use Future<List<QuestionStruct>>. Or return a Runnable if you are really expecting to return something before even getting an answer.

Comment: @LéonPelletier, neither of those things are in Swift, are they?

Comment: You are mixing Swift and Java. Swift is used on iOS, Java on Android. Future and Runnable are in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a the number one misunderstanding about asynchronous functions: the code underneath the find function does not run after the find function.  It runs before it.

The last log statement in the function logs, and the return statement returns an empty list, because that list is populated later, after the find is done and the results are returned.  Anything you do that depend on `LOCALparseQuestionList` being populated must be done within the find's callback.