# Array retuning a blank array outside of PFQuery with Parse.

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Array returning a blank array when outside of the PFQuery. For some reason, the items are not being passed to the array when compiled.

```
class DriverViewController: UIViewController {
var placesArr : Array<Place> = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)


    var query = PFQuery(className:"places")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:"email@email.com")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
             let x = Place(aIdent: (object["Ident"] as! Int), aName: (object["name"] as! String), aAddress: (object["originAddress"] as! String), aCity: (object["originCity"] as! String), aCategoryName: (object["catName"] as! String), aLat: (object["aLat"] as! String), aLng: (object["aLng"] as! String))

                    self.placesArr.append(x)
                    println(placesArr) //****It works here and prints an array****
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
 println(placesArr) //****But here it returns a blank array and this is where I need it to return an array****
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a very common misunderstanding relating to threading, the issue is what order events run:

```
// Runs 1st
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Runs 3rd
}
// Runs 2nd
println(placesArr)
```

The execution of the program doesn't halt when you call `findObjectsInBackground`, it finds objects: `inBackground` which means the heavy lifting of a network request is dispatched to a different queue so that the user can still interact with the screen.  A simple way to do this would be to do:

```
var placesArray: [Place] = [] {
    didSet {
        // Do any execution that needs to wait for places array here.
    }
}
```

You can also trigger subsequent actions within the parse response block, I just personally find executing behavior dependent on a property update being executed in `didSet` to be a nice way to control flow.

Comment: Thanks Logan! The placing is important. For it to work, var placesArray: [Place] = [] {
    didSet {
        // Do any execution that needs to wait for places array here.
    }
} Needs to go before the PFQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Logan's answer is right in the money.

See my answer in this thread: [Storing values in completionHandlers - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235082/storing-values-in-completionhandlers-swift/30235391#30235391)

I wrote up a detailed description of how async completion handlers work, and in the comments there is a link to a working example project the illustrates it.

Comment: I feel like I do one of these a day, such as this one yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493949/unable-to-use-the-result-of-a-parsequery/30495060#30495060.  I thought you had written a general purpose question and answer about this, but couldn't locate it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is a block operation that performs in the background - it's asynchronous.

The line `println(placesArr)` actually executes before the block is finished - that's why you see `nil` there.